# Infer the type of a generic on an interface

Tags: typescript

This may be a duplicate, as I imagine it's a relatively common problem, but I wasn't able to find anything unfortunately.

If I want to define a function that takes a generic, typescript is often able to infer the type of the generic:

```js
const f = <T>(x: Record<string, T>) => x;

const x = f({ a: { x: 1 }, b: { x: 1 } });
```

Typescript has no problem here, and I don't need to provide the type of the generic.

If, however, I try and do the same thing in an interface, I can't; I need to explicitly provide the type:

```js
type X<T> = Record<string, T>;

const x: X = { a: { x: 1 }, b: { x: 1 } };
```

In some ways I can see why this is; we can define the type of a variable before we actually give it a value, so the generic isn't always inferable. But neither can I do this:

```js
const x = { a: { x: 1 }, b: { x: 1 } } as X;
```

It seems as though it's part of the language's syntax that for types and interfaces, you have to explicitly provide the type of generics; but am I missing something? Can anyone provide any help at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this is being worked upon, see [issue-26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) , in particular [issue-26242-comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242#issuecomment-411084229) (and also [issue-30120](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30120) , which looks very similar to your example here ) :

> Maybe adopt the `?` from the partial application proposal
>
> `foo<?, ?, string>(); // returns [{}, {}, string]`
>
> which already stands for `optional` in TypeScript. Actually, the meaning of would be pretty similar to the proposal and could allow for something like this:
>
> `type Foo<T, U, V> = T | U | V;`
>
> `type Bar = Foo<?, string, ?>; // equal to type Bar<A, B> = A | string | B;`

(I found this by searching for 2314 , the error code that is currently given by the playground reg. your code snippet, I have previously had success with searching on the error codes).

Comment: Great answer! Glad to know I'm not the only one with the problem. I'll wait a little while and see if any other answers come in, otherwise this will be the accepted answer